# Setting dynamic baseUrl for Get Request RestClient

Tags: c#, rest, api, rest-client

I am wanting to dynamically change my baseUrl for my RestClient depending on what token is being run.

This is for the deputy roster systems attempting to get Roster data out but cannot figure out how to get a custom baseUrl for each token

```
public List<DeputyRosterData> RosterData(string url, int? actual, int? roster)
{
        BaseUrl = "e1f5c520093734.au.deputy.com";      //Error on this line but to show you what I need
        var request = Request("/api/v1/resource/Roster");
        var result = _client.Execute<List<DeputyRosterData>>(request);
        return result.Data;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think, It's useful for u

```
        var client = new RestClient();
        string baseURL = "http://northwind.servicestack.net";
        string apiURL = baseURL + "/" + "customers?format=json";
        client = new RestClient(apiURL); // 1 URL 
        var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);            
        IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
        baseURL = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com";
        apiURL = baseURL + "/posts/1";
        client = new RestClient(apiURL);//2 URL
        request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);            
        response = client.Execute(request);
```